# After set localization in Datatables needed change label text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am using https://datatables.net/ for my tables. I need localization in this tables witch will set like this:

```
            $('#tableId').dataTable( {

                "language": {
                    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/i18n/Slovak.json"
                },
                ...
```

but at search input is label which i do not want... Is there any way in init. set label hidden? or empty string? I was trying (after localization set)

```
                ...
                language: {
                    "sSearch": ""
                }
```

or

```
                ...
                oLanguage: {
                    "sSearch": ""
                }
```

but without result... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the `language` settings once they are set, without recreating the table. You could load the language JSON first, modify it and then initialise the datatable. Or you could simply strip out plain text from the filter / search filter `<label>` :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  ...
  initComplete : function() {
    $('.dataTables_filter label').contents().filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType === 3 //TEXT_NODE¹
    }).remove()
  }
})
```

The loop is necessary due to the nature of the injected markup :

```
<div class="dataTables_filter">
  <label>
     Search
     <input />
  </label>
</div>
```

So we cant just use `.text('')` or similar.

¹ https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247